# edit video using QtFFmpegWrapper

Tags: c++, qt, video, ffmpeg, wrapper

Everybody knows how to edit video using QtFFmpegWrapper?
I want to create a simple application to play a video and I want to add a little more functionality, for example make video black and white

Comment: It doesn't look like it is maintained any more, or in the last 3 years.

Comment: what about using old version ?